# Remove connecting lines in ggplot2 geom_polygon

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2, polygon

I've made the map below by subsetting a shapefile downloaded from www.gadm.org :

```
load(url('http://gadm.org/data/rda/GBR_adm0.RData'))
library(ggplot2)
ukMapFort <- fortify(gadm)
ukMapFortSub <- subset(ukMapFort, lat > 55.575 & lat < 55.739 & long > -1.929 & long < -1.7)
ggplot() + geom_polygon(data=data.frame(ukMapFortSub), aes(long, lat, group=id), fill=NA, color="black")
```

[image]

How can I remove the two red lines? Note I've coloured the lines red using Photoshop - these lines are produced by R code, but are not coloured red by R code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you need to plot just borders then you can use `geom_path()` and column `group` for `group=`. You also have to add `coord_map()` in this case to maintain right aspect ratio between x and y axis.

```
ggplot(ukMapFortSub,aes(long, lat, group=group))+
  geom_path(color="black")+coord_map()
```

[image]

Comment: note the plot I've uploaded is subtly more 'squashed' than yours. Why is my plot more 'squashed' than yours?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have tried using geom_path() instead of geom_polygon() and the connecting lines are still there. I am plotting the US map.

```
ggplot(US, aes(x=long, y=lat)) +
  borders("state") +
  geom_polygon(alpha = 0.2, fill = NA, color = 'grey60')+
```

Produces ( I added coord_map() later after other stuff plot over the map):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkL4m.png)